# Categorization output

Tags: php

I have a PHP code here:

The code below counts the number of values in certain ranges (4 categories) shown below.

I would like to show the category index number in the html table as output. - not the count -. How can I achieve this? any would be appreciated. thanks.

What I mean with category index number is this :   `$cat[1]` here it is 1.   `$cat[3]` here 3. etc.

Please ask if clarification needed. thanks.

Note: IMPORTANT : if there is no data and no category assigned, so the output would be blank.

```
   <table>
       <tr><th>9:10</th></tr>
       <tr><th>7:8</th></tr>
       <tr><th>5:6</th></tr>
       <tr><th>1:4</th></tr>
      </table>
     
     <?php
    include ("config.php");
    
    $sql = "SELECT grpa, grpb from datatb";
    
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    //categories
    $cat[4] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
    $cat[3] = ["5", "6"];
    $cat[2] = ["7", "8"];
    $cat[1] = ["9", "10"];
    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    
        $columns[1] = array_filter($row, function ($col) use ($cat)
        {
            if (in_array($col, $cat[1]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
        $columns[2] = array_filter($row, function ($col) use ($cat)
        {
            if (in_array($col, $cat[2]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
    
        $columns[3] = array_filter($row, function ($col) use ($cat)
        {
            if (in_array($col, $cat[3]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
    
        $columns[4] = array_filter($row, function ($col) use ($cat)
        {
            if (in_array($col, $cat[4]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
    
        $output[] = $columns;
    }
    
    // the output
    $table = <<<EOT
     
  EOT;
    
    foreach($output as $row) {      
    
    
    $table.="<table>";
    
        foreach($row as $column) {
            $table.="<tr>";
            $table .="<td>";
            $table .= count($column);   
            $table .="</td>";
              
        }
        
        $table.="</tr>";    
        $table.="</table>";
    }
    
        
    echo $table;
    
    ?>
```

sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `datatb` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grpa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grpb` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `datatb`
--

INSERT INTO `datatb` (`id`, `grpa`, `grpb`) VALUES
(1, 1, 5),
(2, 4, 6),
(3, 8, 9),
(4, 3, 3),
(5, 5, 4),
(6, 7, 8),
(7, 9, 10),
(8, 10, 5),
(9, 10, 9);
```

Expected table output:

[image]

so these values are category index numbers. Here when there are 2 same categories, i showed it comma-separated like 2,2. but if it is easier, it can be shown with one category number 2 instead of 2,2. it won't matter.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT grpa, grpb from datatb;` < is missing a quote. If that was a bad paste, please fix it.

Comment: `EOT;` < you have spaces before that, there should not be. That also will cause a parse error.

Comment: Based on data you provided what it is output you want to get?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Actually now it depends on PHP version. PHP7.3 allows indentation for closing tag.  https://laravel-news.com/flexible-heredoc-and-nowdoc-coming-to-php-7-3

Comment: Wouldn't `foreach($row as $index => $column)` work to get you the current row index?

Comment: how would it work? and if there's no data, it should blank.

Comment: @Tajni, what happened to your solution? it was not the right one for this?